# HTML, CSS: Append inline-element to the right of a centered inline-element

Tags: html, css, center, inline

(The title might sound stupid but I don't know how to put it more sophisticated.)

As you can see in the follwing screenshots, I have 3 stacked divs.

[image]

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <div class="center-horizontal-inline">
    <a class="upvote" href="#" data-id="iZheLNnewWtMhPTQd">
  </div>
<div class="score">
  115
  <span class="badge score-diff vertical-align"> +5 </span>
</div>
<div class="center-horizontal-inline">
</div>
```

The one in the middle contains the number (115). The other two the vote-arrows. For the one containing the number, I want to add a "badge" (in bootstrap context) right next to the number, let's say to the right. You can see my attempt shining through the colored overlay.

The goal is to leave the number centered respectively to the arrow-icons, while placing the badge with an offset (or "right next to")  respectively to the number.

My attempt was to set a `float: right;` for the badge, but as you can see, the number has an offset now. When I try `position: absolute;` on the badge, there is no offset (as wanted), but I can't get the badge right next to the number, I can only attach it to the right border because I don't have the number as positioning-reference anymore.

Hope my explanation was clear enough. I also didn't know how to search for that problem...

**EDIT 1:**

As I want it to look like (positioning-wise):

[image: ui-ideal]

Comment: Have you tried to set absolute position on the +5 box?

Comment: just reformatted the text. please check OP again

Comment: is it ok to wrap "115" in to a span tag?

Comment: sure. I'm okay with any html-modification

Comment: Please create an easily test- and modify-able example for stuff like this, f.e. on http://jsfiddle.net/, http://codepen.io/ or similar services. Or at least post actual _code_ that can be used via copy&paste, instead of an _image of_ code …

Comment: replaced the image with the copypastable html code. You're right, that was dumb, I'm not used to ask code-related things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go, using relative and absolute positions together:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/1qbo7uwn/

HTML

```
<div class="score">
    <span class="score-wrap">
        <span class="score-main">123</span>
        <span class="score-diff">8</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.score {
    width: 80px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.score-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.score-main {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.score-diff {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid red;
    left: 100%;
    top: -2px;
}
```

Added some span tags in the HTML.

**EDIT:** vertical align of everything, by setting line height.

http://jsfiddle.net/1qbo7uwn/1/

Comment: Thank you, it works! Any idea how to vertical-centerize the badge now beside a workaround like `top: 23%`? But I guess it has to be something like this, since it's absolutely positioned now...

Comment: I also tried `line-height` first, but realized that this stretches the bootstrap-badge vertically. maybe with nesting two spans, the inner one with standard line-height?

Answer (score 2):

As you said you are okay with HTML modification. Here's my attempt:

[Demo Fiddle](http://codepen.io/sonu/pen/PwyKzK)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="vote up">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <span class="score">115
    <span class="badge">+5</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote inactive">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
  margin: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
.vote{
  font-size:36px;
}
.up{
  color:green;
}
.down{
  color:red;
}
.inactive{
  color:gray;
}
.score{
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.badge{
  background: #eee;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Looks the same like to solution from @sdcr, and I already implemented his

Answer (score 2):

Try

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/rjv1xxo2/1/

```css
.center-horizontal-inline {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
.score {
    text-align: center;
}
.score:after {
    content:attr(data-badge);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: .4em;
    font-size: x-small;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="center-horizontal-inline vote"> <a href="#" data-id="iZheLNnewWtMhPTQd"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>

    </div>
    <div class="score" data-badge="+5">115</div>
    <div class="center-horizontal-inline"> <a href="#" data-id="iZheLNnewWtMhPTQd"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
```